# how to keep listening to a an inputstream in java

Tags: java, android, inputstream

I am working on an Android app which has an i/o streams opened to a pc app, I want to keep an eye on the inputStream and get notified when new data comes from the pc side. Currently I am while(true)-ing {istream.read()} and once it does not through an error I know that something new just arrived so I do the propper action. Is there a better way to keep listening to the inputStream? Is this a correct way for listening?

```
//assume we have inputStream instance
while(true) {
    val bytes = ByteArray(size)
    try {
        inputStream.read(bytes, 0, size)
        //consume the bytes!
    }catch(e: Exception) {
        //do nothing because nothing arrived
    }
}
```

Comment: You should really post your code rather than describe it.  But yes, istream.read is blocking, so just reading from it on its own thread in an infinite loop is one common way of doing things.

Comment: isn't that going to affect efficiency? @GabeSechan

Comment: No, that's why you do it on its own thread.  Since its a blocking call, it will yield the processor to the OS until data is available, so the core can be reused.  You might get slightly better performance out of using select across multiple sockets, or even nio.  But for a single socket you won't notice the difference.

Comment: Don't ignore the value returned by `read()`. It could be -1, indicating end of stream, whereupon you should close the socket and exit the loop. There is no inefficiency in blocking. You don't need to allocate a new buffer every time around the loop. There is no [tag:nio] here. Don't tag indiscriminately.

Comment: very precious advice, thanks :) @user207421